# DateTime weird transformation

Tags: javascript, date

I should transform my JS date in this format

> 2017-05-22T12:31:41.129+0100

which I'm not sure if it's a standard or not, but basically my `new Date();` retrive this output:

> Wed Aug 02 2017 20:11:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)

Is there any function to retrieve this standard (?) or should I concatenate all the results?

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear, you want a function that transforms the result of `new Date()` to the `2017-05-22T12:31:41.129+0100` format?

Comment: @AGE Yes, that is my goal, I guess I have to implement a function that concatenate all the results of .getFullYear(); etc?

Comment: I think that is quite similar to an SQL standard, but there is also a T in the middle and +GMT at the end

Comment: That is a non standard format. Closest built in is `Date#toISOString()`. which produces: `"2017-05-22T11:31:41.129Z"`

Comment: @charlietfl what that Z stands for? Should I split for the Z and concat the GMT?

Comment: `Z` is for Zulu time (Zero offset) .... GMT timezone

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: The question doesn't demonstrate any effort on OP's part.

Comment: @GoingSolo `Z` indicates that the date/time [is in UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC), so if you remove it and add the GMT part, the result will be incorrect (because the date and time won't  be adjusted accordingly). Example: in my machine, `new Date().toISOString()` produces `2017-08-02T18:38:52.157Z`, but the local time (in my timezone) is `2017-08-02T15:38:52.157-03:00`, while in Italy it'll be `2017-08-02T20:38:52.157+02:00`

Answer (score -2):

If you have a date with `new Date();` and you want to recieve this long string just do:

```
let x = new Date();
console.log(x.toString());
```

To convert the first string into a date object try the funtion `Date.parse(dateString)`.

If you want to get exactly this first string format, you have to concat all parts of it manually, yes.

Comment: *Date.parse* does not return a Date object.